# Javascript wont replace my <div> text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have made a Javascript that will replace the text in the Div with the text that I put in my input

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
    <body>
        <form>
            <input type="text" id="div1" />
            <input type="text" id="div2" />
            <input type="text" id="div3" />
            <button type="button" onclick="ChangeText()">Submit</button>
        </form>

        <div id="Div5">
            Text goes here
        </div>

        <script>
            function ChangeText()
            {
                // Place text in page
                var test1 = document.getElementById("div1").value;
                var test2 = document.getElementById("div2").value;
                var test3 = document.getElementById("div3").value;
                var test = test1 + "</br>" + test2 + "</br>" + test3;
                document.getElementById("Div5").innerHTML = test;
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

But it wont change it, nothing happens.
EDIT:
The answers I got work for a normal HTML page. But I should have probably added that I need this to work on a jQuery mobile page.
I hope anyone can help me with that?

Comment: There is no such thing as `</input>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `button` tag inside a form has `type='submit'` by default, so when you click the form will be submited and the page will be refreshed so you will not see the change on the `div`'s, change it to `type='button'` to avoid that :

```
<button type='button' onclick="ChangeText()">Submit</button>
```

**NOTE :** `input` tag is one of the self-closing tags so it should be :

```
<input type="text" id="div1" />
```

Instead of :

```
<input type="text" id="div1"></input>
```

Hope this helps.

```js
function ChangeText()
{
  // Place text in page
  var test1 = document.getElementById("div1").value;
  var test2 = document.getElementById("div2").value;
  var test3 = document.getElementById("div3").value;
  var test = test1 + "</br>" + test2 + "</br>" + test3;
  document.getElementById("Div5").innerHTML = test;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" id="div1" /> 
  <input type="text" id="div2" />
  <input type="text" id="div3" />
  <button onclick="ChangeText()">Submit</button>
</form>

<div id="Div5">
  Text goes here
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, now it does indeed work if I try on a normal HTML page, I kind of forgot to include that I need to do this on a Jquery mobile page. Maybe you have some advice on that?

Comment: <script async src="//jsfiddle.net/fvUHA/54/embed/js,html,result/"></script>

Answer (score 3):

As you have not given any `button` **type** and **button is in form** that's why it's by default taken as **submit button**. And after completing your JS code it's automatically submitted the form.

Your code is almost correct except the htlml button tag please follow below::

Please replace your button tag with this ::

```
<button type="button" onclick="ChangeText();">Submit</button>
```

**OR**

```
<button onclick="ChangeText(); return false;">Submit</button>
```

It will worked perfectly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it really helped but I hope you see my edit

Answer (score 1):

You need to change

```
<button onclick="ChangeText()">Submit</button>
```

to

```
<button type='button' onclick="ChangeText()">Submit</button>
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" id="div1"> </input>
  <input type="text" id="div2"> </input>
  <input type="text" id="div3"> </input>
  <button type='button' onclick="ChangeText()">Submit</button>
</form>

<div id="Div5">
  Text goes here
</div>

<script>
  function ChangeText() {
    // Place text in page
    var test1 = document.getElementById("div1").value;
    var test2 = document.getElementById("div2").value;
    var test3 = document.getElementById("div3").value;
    var test = test1 + "</br>" + test2 + "</br>" + test3;
    document.getElementById("Div5").innerHTML = test;
  }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace Your code with

```
    <!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
 <body>
 <form>
 <input type="text" id="div1"> </input> <input type="text" id="div2">
 </input>
 <input type="text" id="div3"> </input> 

 <script> function ChangeText() { 
    // Place text in page 
    var test1 = document.getElementById("div1").value;
     var test2 = document.getElementById("div2").value; 
     var test3 = document.getElementById("div3").value;
      var test = test1 + "</br>" + test2 + "</br>" + test3;
       document.getElementById("Div5").innerHTML = test; 
       } </script> 

 <input onclick="ChangeText()" type=button value=Submit > 
</form> 
<div id="Div5"> Text goes here </div>
 </body> 
</html>
```